# How do i call a variable from one method/ or create a field variable from it

Tags: java

I need to use the `args[2]` instead of the `1.12` in balloon 2 same for `args[0]` and `args[1]` but that's for later in the program. There is a frame and everything I removed them, thought the site was asking me to do so.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ProportionalBalons extends JPanel {

    public void runArguments(String[] args) {
        String currencyCostumerHas = args[0];
        String currencyCostumerWants = args[1];
        String USDollarToEUEuroexchangeValueS = args[2];
        int exchangeValue = new Integer(USDollarToEUEuroexchangeValueS).intValue();
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        double balon1Diameter = costumerDeposit;
        double balon2Diameter = costumerDeposit * 1.12;
        //ballon 1
        g.drawOval(10, 10, balon1Diameter, balon1Diameter);
        //ballon 2 
        g.drawOval(60 * 8, 10, balon2Diameter, balon2Diameter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Is passing it in as an argument to `paintComponent` not an option?

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning That's a `JPanel`, so `paintComponent` is an overridden method of a superclass. So no, it can't be changed.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Ah, makes sense then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the information you get from `runArguments`. I think actually what you want is a *constructor*:

```
public class ProportionalBalons extends JPanel {
    private String currencyCostumerHas;
    private String currencyCostumerWants;
    private double exchangeRate = args[2];

    public ProportionalBalons(int currencyCustumerHas, String currencyCustumerWants, exchangeRate) {
        this.currencyCostumerHas = currencyCostumerHas;
        this.currencyCostumerWants = currencyCostumerWants;
        this.exchangeRate = exchangeRate;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        double balon1Diameter = costumerDeposit;
        double balon2Diameter = costumerDeposit * exchangeRate;
        //ballon 1
        g.drawOval(10, 10, balon1Diameter, balon1Diameter);
        //ballon 2 
        g.drawOval(60 * 8, 10, balon2Diameter, balon2Diameter);
    }
}
```

Here, when you create a new `ProportionalBalons` object, you will capture the values of your arguments and they will be available to all the methods defined in `ProportionalBalons`.

A few notes:

1. I didn't see any use of the "currency" variables, but I put them in there because it looks like you probably do actually need them.
2. There is no definition of the `customerDeposit` in your existing code; I assume it's somewhere. If you must, you can capture it in the constructor as well.
3. The exchange rate certainly shouldn't be an `int`. If the USD is either `1x` or `2x` EUR, then I'll pick `1x`, please (I get paid in USD). I've made this a `double`.

Comment: Yeah that makes way more sense than my suggestion. Deleting my answer

Answer (score 0):

If your args[] variable is declared and initialized outside of your paintComponent() and runArguments() methods then you should be able to call it from within paintComponent.

```
double balon2Diameter=costumerDeposit*args[2];
```

If the variable is only local then it won't work.